# Impersonation the current user using WindowsImpersonationContext to access network drive

Tags: c#, .net, security, impersonation, remote-access

I need to access a remote drive from a Web App. The drive isn't accessible to the ASP.NET process, so I want to impersonate the current user for the request.

I saw some basic examples using WindowsImpersonationContext, and have tried the following.

```
WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext = null;

try
{
    impersonationContext = ((WindowsIdentity)User.Identity).Impersonate();

    file.SaveAs(filePath);
}
finally
{
    if (impersonationContext != null)
    {
        impersonationContext.Undo();
    }
}
```

I'm still getting an access denied exception.

I've read a bit of stuff about `LogonUser`, but as far as I can tell you need a user name and password to get credentials from that. I'm not looking to log in as a different specific user, just the current user (who should have permissions to access the file store), so I don't think I actually need the `LogonUser` API.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm missing? Should the above code work?

I'd also note that including

`<identity impersonate="true" />`

doesn't work, but including

`<identity impersonate="true" userName="myName" password="myPassword" />`

in the `web.config` lets me in. I've seen a few people ask questions about why this is, but I've seen no explanation. I'm wondering if it is connected to my problem though.

Comment: Is the web site running an Anonymous or Windows Identity?

Comment: @Vivek: IIS is set up to use Window identity. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

I wrote a helper class that does it:

```
public static class ImpersonationUtils
{
    private const int SW_SHOW = 5;
    private const int TOKEN_QUERY = 0x0008;
    private const int TOKEN_DUPLICATE = 0x0002;
    private const int TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY = 0x0001;
    private const int STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW = 0x00000001;
    private const int STARTF_FORCEONFEEDBACK = 0x00000040;
    private const int CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT = 0x00000400;
    private const int TOKEN_IMPERSONATE = 0x0004;
    private const int TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE = 0x0010;
    private const int TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES = 0x0020;
    private const int TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS = 0x0040;
    private const int TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT = 0x0080;
    private const int TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID = 0x0100;
    private const int STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0x000F0000;
    private const int TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS =
        STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED |
        TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY |
        TOKEN_DUPLICATE |
        TOKEN_IMPERSONATE |
        TOKEN_QUERY |
        TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE |
        TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES |
        TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS |
        TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT |
        TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
    {
        public IntPtr hProcess;
        public IntPtr hThread;
        public int dwProcessId;
        public int dwThreadId;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    {
        public int nLength;
        public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
        public bool bInheritHandle;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct STARTUPINFO
    {
        public int cb;
        public string lpReserved;
        public string lpDesktop;
        public string lpTitle;
        public int dwX;
        public int dwY;
        public int dwXSize;
        public int dwYSize;
        public int dwXCountChars;
        public int dwYCountChars;
        public int dwFillAttribute;
        public int dwFlags;
        public short wShowWindow;
        public short cbReserved2;
        public IntPtr lpReserved2;
        public IntPtr hStdInput;
        public IntPtr hStdOutput;
        public IntPtr hStdError;
    }

    private enum SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL
    {
        SecurityAnonymous,
        SecurityIdentification,
        SecurityImpersonation,
        SecurityDelegation
    }

    private enum TOKEN_TYPE
    {
        TokenPrimary = 1,
        TokenImpersonation
    }

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool CreateProcessAsUser(
        IntPtr hToken,
        string lpApplicationName,
        string lpCommandLine,
        ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
        ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
        bool bInheritHandles,
        int dwCreationFlags,
        IntPtr lpEnvironment,
        string lpCurrentDirectory,
        ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
        out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool DuplicateTokenEx(
        IntPtr hExistingToken,
        int dwDesiredAccess,
        ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
        int ImpersonationLevel,
        int dwTokenType,
        ref IntPtr phNewToken);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool OpenProcessToken(
        IntPtr ProcessHandle,
        int DesiredAccess,
        ref IntPtr TokenHandle);

    [DllImport("userenv.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool CreateEnvironmentBlock(
            ref IntPtr lpEnvironment,
            IntPtr hToken,
            bool bInherit);

    [DllImport("userenv.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool DestroyEnvironmentBlock(
            IntPtr lpEnvironment);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool CloseHandle(
        IntPtr hObject);

    private static void LaunchProcessAsUser(string cmdLine, IntPtr token, IntPtr envBlock, int sessionId)
    {
        var pi = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
        var saProcess = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
        var saThread = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
        saProcess.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(saProcess);
        saThread.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(saThread);

        var si = new STARTUPINFO();
        si.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(si);
        si.lpDesktop = @"WinSta0\Default";
        si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW | STARTF_FORCEONFEEDBACK;
        si.wShowWindow = SW_SHOW;

        if (!CreateProcessAsUser(
            token,
            null,
            cmdLine,
            ref saProcess,
            ref saThread,
            false,
            CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT,
            envBlock,
            null,
            ref si,
            out pi))
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), "CreateProcessAsUser failed");
        }
    }

    private static IDisposable Impersonate(IntPtr token)
    {
        var identity = new WindowsIdentity(token);
        return identity.Impersonate();
    }

    private static IntPtr GetPrimaryToken(Process process)
    {
        var token = IntPtr.Zero;
        var primaryToken = IntPtr.Zero;

        if (OpenProcessToken(process.Handle, TOKEN_DUPLICATE, ref token))
        {
            var sa = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
            sa.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(sa);

            if (!DuplicateTokenEx(
                token,
                TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS,
                ref sa,
                (int)SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityImpersonation,
                (int)TOKEN_TYPE.TokenPrimary,
                ref primaryToken))
            {
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), "DuplicateTokenEx failed");
            }

            CloseHandle(token);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), "OpenProcessToken failed");
        }

        return primaryToken;
    }

    private static IntPtr GetEnvironmentBlock(IntPtr token)
    {
        var envBlock = IntPtr.Zero;
        if (!CreateEnvironmentBlock(ref envBlock, token, false))
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), "CreateEnvironmentBlock failed");
        }
        return envBlock;
    }

    public static void LaunchAsCurrentUser(string cmdLine)
    {
        var process = Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer").FirstOrDefault();
        if (process != null)
        {
            var token = GetPrimaryToken(process);
            if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                var envBlock = GetEnvironmentBlock(token);
                if (envBlock != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    LaunchProcessAsUser(cmdLine, token, envBlock, process.SessionId);
                    if (!DestroyEnvironmentBlock(envBlock))
                    {
                        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), "DestroyEnvironmentBlock failed");
                    }
                }

                CloseHandle(token);
            }
        }
    }

    public static IDisposable ImpersonateCurrentUser()
    {
        var process = Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer").FirstOrDefault();
        if (process != null)
        {
            var token = GetPrimaryToken(process);
            if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                return Impersonate(token);
            }
        }

        throw new Exception("Could not find explorer.exe");
    }
}
```

You can use it like that:

```
ImpersonationUtils.LaunchAsCurrentUser("notepad");

using (ImpersonationUtils.ImpersonateCurrentUser())
{

}
```

More explanations and examples you can find here :

[Impersonating CurrentUser from SYSTEM](http://amiryonatan.blogspot.co.il/2013/01/impersonating-currentuser_26.html)

Comment: Hi, I used your code to Console.WriteLine the WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name on a remote computer, in which another user was logged, using psexec. It crashed at line "if (OpenProcessToken(process.Handle, TOKEN_DUPLICATE, ref token))" throwing a negative error code which, I was unable to find out what it meant. What did I miss? Thanks.  EDIT: I am inside a Domain in which both my user an the one in the other computer are Admins

Comment: I've been banging my head for 2 days on that problem! Every call to Active Directory was crashing when using Chrome. Your class did it! Works like a charm and easy to use! THANK YOU!!

Comment: Worked great. Amazing stuff.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!

Comment: If this accidentally selects an Explorer instance running as admin, it will have admin right, correct?

Answer (score 3):

You're probably running into an Impersonation vs. Delegation issue. When you Impersonate a user, you can access local resources as that user, but not remote resources.  With Delegation, you can access remote resources too.  Try the following:

1. Ensure that Windows authentication is enabled in IIS, and that Anonymous authentication is disabled (Anonymous authentication takes precedence of other authentication mechanisms)
2. Enable `<authentication mode="Windows" />` in your web.config to ensure ASP.NET processes Windows authentication (this should only apply to Classic pipeline mode).
3. `<identity impersonate="true" />` should be enough.

The other thing you may need to do, is ensure that the the account running the AppPool is permitted to act like a delegate.

Comment: I have this all set up already, and it's not working. Could you explain a little more what you mean on the last point, *ensure that the the account running the AppPool is permitted to act like a delegate*? I'm not sure what you mean by this, do you have a link? Thanks

Comment: You need to ensure that your service account running your application pool is configured for Kerberos delegation.  This is often a huge pain, but at a minimum ensure that the account is trusted for delegation to any service in Active Directory (on the Delegation tab) and that there's an SPN registered for your web app's host name against the service account.  You'll also need to ensure the app pool is running under the context of the service account by setting "useAppPoolCredentials = true" in the web config.  You won't see the Delegation tab until there's an SPN registered against the account