# System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException occurs only with Google Chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, asp.net-mvc-4, impersonation, iis-8.5

MVC application with `ApplicationPoolIdentity` on a remote IIS 8.5. Works fine with IE11 but when using Google Chrome, I get a yellow screen with `System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException`

This is the code causing the error

```
 protected void Session_Start()
    {
        // Load current AD user
        UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.Current;
        Session.Add(name: "DisplayName", value: user.DisplayName);
        Session.Add(name: "AccountName", value: user.SamAccountName);
    }
```

Also in my Web.config file I have `<identity impersonate="true" />` and `<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />` that last bit is the only way I found to make things work. But it only works in IE.

Why is it working fine in IE11 but not in Chrome? What am I doing wrong?

### UPDATE #1

I can make it work when using `HostingEnvironment.Impersonate()` to wrap every calls to Active Directory. But it still giving me a yellow screen when I try to alter an account in AD with `user.Save()`

`System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access denied.`

I don't have full access to Active Directory Domain but I can reset password and enable/disable accounts in my OU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14545336/75172

Using this class to wrap every calls to AD solved my problem.